# What is this soft plastic like material that has been added to the window, and how best to remove it?

Tags: repair, materials

[image]

The previous owner added this soft, plastic like material to the window frame and I'd like to remove it. I can get parts off with a knife, and when I do it is flexible and soft.

I believe this is probably a common material, but I'm struggling to identify it. What is it? And how best would you go about moving it from the window?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: It's either bird poop or caulk.  Presuming it's caulk, most home improvement stores sell a "caulk remover" paste that might help remove i.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Likely "removable caulk", (perhaps "temporary caulk" - been a few years since I put some on leaky windows for the winter) in which case pulling it once you get an edge lifted up should be effective at removing it, though perhaps complicated by it being a sloppy job...

Otherwise, just (clear?) caulk, and it might be harder to remove. Using a knife will risk scratching things up - a plastic scraping tool might be a better choice, depending on the window material. Then again, you may just have to plan on repainting.

Comment: Repainting over it isn't an option as there's so much of it it stops the window closing, and I can only peel like 5mm up at best, but as you say it's a sloppy job. I'll go with Caulk and get some removers for it. Thanks.

Comment: It's worth trying the stuff that's advertised to loosen silicone caulk. And a plastic razor blade will reduce the scratching damage to the frame.

Comment: Repainting was intended to address the scratches from aggressive removal, not to be over the lumpy caulk.